# MYSQL to calculate YTD

Tags: mysql

I am starting to learn MYSQL and have an issue at hand that I cannot figure out. My table looks like this:

`OU Date    Amt
A20 201701  1000
A20 201705  1000
A20 201708  1000
B10 201702  1000
B10 201705  1000`

What I would like is to calculate the YTD amount for each row by OU that looks like this:

`OU Date     Amt    YTD
A20 201701  1000    1000
A20 201705  1000    2000
A20 201708  1000    3000
B10 201702  1000    1000
B10 201705  1000    2000`

I tried different sum and sumif functions but couldn't get the correct results. Can anyone help? Any input is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach uses a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT
    OU,
    Date,
    Amt,
    (SELECT SUM(t2.Amt) FROM yourTable t2
     WHERE t1.OU = t2.OU AND t2.Date <= t1.Date) AS YTD
FROM
    yourTable t1
ORDER BY
    OU, Date;
```

The trick the subquery uses is to sum, for each record in your table, the amounts of the current or earlier dates, from those records sharing the same `OU` value as the current record.  You can explore the demo below to get a better understanding.

**Demo here:**

## Rextester